# Deploy a pruned Tron (TRC20) node

Tags: blockchain, pruning, tron

Tron main net (TRC20) is about 500GB nowadays and needs much server config!
I'm searching for a way to prune the network like the pruning method in Bitcoin nodes or light or fast sync modes in Ethereum Blockchain.

Does anybody know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should stop your node then you can use the tools provided by Tron, e.g:

> java -jar LiteFullNodeTool.jar -o split -t snapshot --fn-data-path
> output-directory/database --dataset-path
> liteDatabase/output-directory/

You can also refer to this [issue](https://github.com/tronprotocol/java-tron/issues/4731#issue-1422011722) about this subject for more information.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: You might want to consider formatting your answer in a more clear and concise manner, @AlirezaO.